# OCMock and overriding stub value

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

```
mockModule = OCMPartialMock(module);
OCMStub([mockModule send:@"FOO"]).andReturn(YES);
OCMStub([mockModule send:@"FOO"]).andReturn(NO);
```

In this example I have a simple mock module, and I set some stubs to return YES/NO when sent a String, the problem that occurs is that if I set the same string twice it only returns the first value, and not the new value.

In this example about the problem is demonstrated like so I would expect a call such as:

```
BOOL answer = [module send:@"FOO"]
//answer should be NO, but is YES
```

How can I make it respond with the most recently set value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *expect* methods, e.g.

`mockModule = OCMPartialMock(module);
OCMExpect([mockModule send:@"FOO"]).andReturn(YES);
OCMStub([mockModule send:@"FOO"]).andReturn(NO);`

That's not exactly what they are meant for, but it does make some sense. You're basically saying, I expect that `send:` will be called, and when that has actually happened, then I want the method to be stubbed.

Also, if it were possible to "pile up" the stubs, figuring out what went wrong would be quite difficult, e.g. if the first invocation of the stub doesn't happen, then the second invocation will get the value meant for the first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  For my unit testing on Android I use Mockito, and in that they have the chaining feature.  For my apps I find it very useful, as I use it to simulate communication with an external device which has states.  In that you can set things like ... when(mockModule.send("FOO").thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);

To achieve the same result with OCMock I used "andCall" to call my own method which contains a list of items to return in order.